# How to broadcast in messenger platform?

Tags: facebook-messenger, messenger

There is a way to broadcast message to many (or to all) users who added bot to their contact list?
Or I need to use `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages` for each of users?

Comment: did you find any alternatives?

Comment: @SandeshBSuvarna no

Answer (score 2):

Facebook has introduced Broadcast API that allows you to send messages to all open conversations. You can also label users so that broadcast will be sent to a specific label: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/broadcast-api

Answer (score 2):

Facebook now supports the [broadcast](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/broadcast-messages) API

Your page need to have the following permissions:

- `pages_messaging`
- `pages_messaging_subscriptions`

Steps to take:

1. Create a Broadcast Message

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{    
  "messages":[
    <MESSAGE_OBJECT>
  ]
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/me/message_creatives?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

2. Store the response BROADCAST_MESSAGE_ID

```
{
  "message_creative_id": <BROADCAST_MESSAGE_ID>,
}
```

3. Send a Broadcast Message

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{    
  "message_creative_id": <BROADCAST_MESSAGE_ID>,
  "notification_type": "<REGULAR | SILENT_PUSH | NO_PUSH>",
  "tag": "<MESSAGE_TAG>"
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/me/broadcast_messages?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

4. Store the BROADCAST_ID

```
{
  "broadcast_id": <BROADCAST_ID>
}
```

Comment: Great answer! I'd also like to add that Facebook has a Target Broadcasts API [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/broadcast-messages/target-broadcasts) that allows you to broadcast to a subset of users. It's really easy to implement and is just an extension of this answer.

Comment: @NatKSS Why don't you suggest that as an [edit to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47951071/edit) for future readers?

Comment: It's strange :/ I am unable to suggest edits for this answer since I've been getting this red error dialog "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted...”, even though your code is well-formatted.

Comment: @NatKSS Keep the code inside `<pre>` and `<code>` tags or select code snippet and press **Ctrl** **K**. It should allow

Answer (score 1):

You could keep a running list of ID's for everyone who has interacted with your bot.

Then all you have to do is make a wrapper function for your sendTextMessage function that will loop through all the users in the list and send them the same message